# How to hide "This tab is using your camera or microphone" after call ended

Tags: javascript, sinch

I'm using Sinch javascript SDK to build a browser to browser video calling app.  When the video call is ended with a call to `call.hangup();` in chrome (at least) the red camera icon is still visible with the message "This tab is using your camera or microphone".

How can I hide this warning after the call has ended? Is there a call in the Sinch SDK I should be making, or something in the underlying WebRTC framework?

Comment: I found this github comment to be helpful: https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/issues/76#issuecomment-198257580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following was required: 
`sinchClient.stopActiveConnection();`

Answer (score 5):

You need to ensure that all MediaStreamTracks are stopped. If you have access to the stream from getUserMedia, doing this should help:

`stream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop())`

Comment: Specifically I found that the following worked: callClient.localMediaStream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop())